# How to check if value is not NaN in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a vote script in PHP but I have some syntax error. I'm a real rocky when it comes to PHP so please be kind...

My "doft" value is NaN if not set?

```
if ( ! isset(int) $_POST["doft"] ){
    $new_value_doft = $prev_value_doft + $doft;
    $new_num_votes_doft = $prev_num_votes_doft + 1;
}
else{
    $new_value_doft = $prev_value_doft + $doft;
    $new_num_votes_doft = $prev_num_votes_doft; 
}
```

Comment: isset(int) means nothing at all!

Comment: why can't you simply say if(!isset($_POST["doft"]))

Comment: You're a real **rocky** when it comes to php, I'm not so sure =)

Answer (score 1):

The [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) method checks if a variable or index is actually set. You want to use it like this

```
if( isset( $_POST["doft"] ) ) { }
```

or, to check if it is not set

```
if( !isset( $_POST["doft"] ) ) { }
```

At the same time, you can make sure/check wether the posted value is an integer like using the [is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) method:

```
if( isset( $_POST["doft"] )  && is_int( $_POST["doft"] ) ) { }
```

Or simply use the [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) method

```
if( isset( $_POST["doft"] )  && is_numeric( $_POST["doft"] ) ) { }
```

Your given script should probably look like this:

```
if ( !isset( $_POST["doft"] ) ){
    $new_value_doft = $prev_value_doft + $doft;
    $new_num_votes_doft = $prev_num_votes_doft + 1;
}
else{
    $new_value_doft = $prev_value_doft + $doft;
    $new_num_votes_doft = $prev_num_votes_doft; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function provided by PHP

Just checking isset does not tell you if it is a valid number or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement isn't working.

It should look something like this.

`if (!isset($_POST['doft']))`

What you have now isn't valid, thus the syntax error.